# How to create a MIME mail with an attachment containing extended characters (with accents) using LotusScript

Tags: lotus-notes, mime, lotus, lotusscript

In a LotusScript agent I create a multi-part mail in MIME, using the MIME classes. It works, mails are sent correctly.

There's just one big problem: files with accented characters in their name aren't correctly transferred. The contents are correct, but the name isn't. I've tried in 100 ways, but either it isn't possible or I'm doing something completely wrong.

Here's (part of) my code:

```
Set Me.mc = Me.mr.createChildEntity()
Set Me.mh = Me.mc.CreateHeader("Content-Disposition")
Call Me.mh.SetHeaderVal(disposition + {; filename="} & attName & {";charset="iso-8859-1"} )
Set Me.mh = Me.mc.CreateHeader("Content-ID")
Call Me.mh.SetHeaderVal( |<| & attName & |>| )
Set stream = Me.session.CreateStream
If stream.Open(attFile) Then
    Call Me.mc.SetContentFromBytes(stream, strContentType & {; charset="iso-8859-1"; name="} & attName & {"}, ENC_IDENTITY_BINARY)
    Call stream.Close
End If
```

If I create a mail manually in Notes and send the same file it works, but the file's name is coded. How to pull this one off??

**Update:**
I added the following function to encode attName:

```
Function URLEncode(s As String, cset As String) As String
    Dim v As Variant

    v= Evaluate(|@ReplaceSubstring(@URLEncode("| + cset + |";"| + s + |"); "%"; "=")|)
    URLEncode= "=?" + cset + "?Q?" + v(0) + "?="
End Function
```

Comment: It's worth mentioning that @Functions URLEncode and URLDecode are exponentially faster than writing LotusScript equivalents, so this is one case where Evaluate is definitely the way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could not find any method to encode the parameters. 
Looks like you have to encode the parameter yourself.

```
@URLEncode( encodingFormat ; token )
```

Should encode the string and then yo can add the =?ISO-8859-1?Q? and ?= to the string.

Or you can use `encodeText` from the `javax.mail.internet` package end wrap that in LS2J

Comment: Really?  I'm asking because ?Q? encoding means "quoted printable", which is not the same thing as URLEncoded format.  Oh, wait... I see in your update that you adjusted for converting "%" into "=", which should take care of that.  But the other thing is that 8859 will only work for char values less than 0xff.  LotusScript is dealing with Unicode internally, so if you have to deal with anything outside of the standard Western European characters, you may have to specify UTF8 or UTF16 instead, and I don't think @URLEncode is going to give you that correctly without a lot more tweaking.

Comment: Is there a better way? I do not really have the time to develop JavaMIME objects to replace the NotesMime objects.

Answer (score 1):

I've never embedded files, just images, but it sounds like using @URLEncode may be worth trying.

```
Dim attNameEncoded As String
attNameEncoded = Evaluate({@URLEncode("iso-8859-1"; "} + attName + {")})(0)
Call Me.mc.SetContentFromBytes(stream, strContentType & {; charset="iso-8859-1"; name="} & attNameEncoded & {"}, ENC_IDENTITY_BINARY)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to encode the file name as described here:

The filename may be encoded as defined by [RFC 2231](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2231).